# hook on the_excerpt

Tags: filters, hooks, excerpt

I would like to have the excerpt length formatted + [...] and then keeping the 'read-more' as a button.
I was able to hook the 'excerpt_length' from 55 to 25 and that was fine:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 25;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 9999 );
```

Now, I would like to add a string with 3dots to the excerpt, just right after. And then, I will still have my button: 'readmore'.

```
function three_dots($text){
    //$text = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 20);
    $text = get_the_excerpt() ;  
    $text .= " [...]";
return $text;
}  
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'three_dots', 9999 );
```

If I use the 'excerpt_more' filter, that removes my 'readmore' button and put the 3 dots instead.
Try to combine the both without success. How can I do that?
Thanks for you help.

Comment: your second piece of code implements a filter, but rather than appending `[...]` to the end of the text you first discarded the text with `$text = get_the_excerpt();` destroying anything that the filter has done already, highly unusual and not how filters are meant to work. Have you tried not overwriting `$text` before appending?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your `three_dots` function like this:

```
function three_dots($excerpt) {
    // Append the dots to the existing excerpt.
    $excerpt .= ' [...]';
    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'three_dots');
```

About your 'read more' button, this usually isn't handled by the excerpt itself but is instead added after the excerpt in your theme's template files. If you've got a custom '**read more**' button, you'd typically place it in your theme's template file where you're displaying the excerpt. You can just mod

For instance, in one of your template file, you might have something like:

```
echo get_the_excerpt();
// Here comes your custom 'read more' button
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="read-more-button">Read More</a>';
```

Comment: Thx. My idea was to implement a hook instead of modifying the existing template. The result of your code gives me: <p>the excerpt.</p>
then <p class="more-link">the button readmore</p>
then <span>the three dots</span> (I added the span into the function. 

I imagine I will need to modify the template to get the 3dots right after the text of the excerpt. Thx anyways.

Comment: If you theme uses both filter you can use the `the_excerpt` to add a [...] to the end of your excerpt and use the `excerpt_more` filter and change the output to a "Read more" link instead of a [...]

But if you theme doesn't use the filters properly then you might have to add a custom template for it.